# R- Saving images from a list of URLS with given titles

Tags: r

I am trying to save images from a list of URLS and assign names per another list like was explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32174306/download-url-links-using-r).

**URL**

```
list_examples <- c( "https://www.bluemoonfiberarts.com/newmoon/index.php?main_page=index&amp;cPath=19_20_1632&amp;zenid=7c3hdt095727v28lsbn6nrj184", 
"https://www.bluemoonfiberarts.com/newmoon/index.php?main_page=index&amp;cPath=19_20_1894&amp;zenid=7c3hdt095727v28lsbn6nrj184", 
"https://www.bluemoonfiberarts.com/newmoon/index.php?main_page=index&amp;cPath=19_20_1644&amp;zenid=7c3hdt095727v28lsbn6nrj184")
```

**Designated names**

```
names_examples = c('A Total Eclipse of the Sun', 
'Autumn Moon Glow', 
'Bewitched')
```

**Iterate through the file and download each file with corresponding name:**

```
for (i in 1:length(list_examples )){
    download.file(list_examples [i], destfile =  names_examples [i], mode = 'wb')
}
```

I tried editing the mode to jpg and that didn't work and there's no function for download.jpg

thank you

Comment: It is just hitting the url and. not the image file i.e. you may have to inspect the website and get the url of image `https://www.bluemoonfiberarts.com/newmoon/images/home/BMFA_SockClub2019_HomeGraphic.jpg`

Comment: are you sure you are trying to download images ? the url's refers to web page.

Comment: that's a good point. thank you. can we save the url as a png?

Answer (score 0):

If we `inspect` the website can get the `url` of the image from the `src` (Below is the example that shows the first link and its downloaded output)

```
list_example1 <- "https://www.bluemoonfiberarts.com/newmoon/images/home/BMFA_SockClub2019_HomeGraphic.jpg"
download.file(list_example1, destfile = names_examples[1], mode = "wb")
```

-checking the output

[image]
[image]

---

If we want to save as `.png`, `paste` the suffix into the 'names_examples'

```
download.file(list_example1, destfile = paste0(names_examples[1], 
      ".png"), mode = "wb")
```